# Affecting the selected page only using PageView.Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am attempting to change the UI when a component is the selected or main page in a PageView Builder.

I thought it would be simple logic like the following

```
if (index == slideController.page) {
  // Change color
} else {
  // Different color
}
```

However, what I am finding is that the index and page views are all over the place and don't line up with the UI.

```
flutter: Selecttion index 2
flutter: Page view page 1
flutter: Selecttion index 3
flutter: Page view page 3
flutter: Selecttion index 4
flutter: Page view page 3
flutter: Selecttion index 3
flutter: Page view page 5
flutter: Selecttion index 2
flutter: Page view page 4
flutter: Selecttion index 1
flutter: Page view page 3
```

I assume I have missed something obvious, but I can't seem, to find it and would appreciate some direction if possible.

```
PageView.builder(
                controller: slideController,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print('Selection index $index');
                  print('Page view page ${(slideController.page}');
                  Colors color;
                  if (index == slideController.page) {
                   // Set color
                  } else {
                    // Set different color
                   }
                  return Container(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    color: color,
                    height: 500,
                    width: 100,
                   
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Using print within a component that is rebuilt several times during the animation transition is not a good test measure, I run your example with a difference and added a listener to the pagecontroller to update a variable with scroll.page and change the container string whenever equals the index and ran as expected. [Gif movie](https://share.getcloudapp.com/7KupWvY1)

Comment: @JustCase I added a listener and it is working fine. Seems odd though that the widget onPageChange listener should be problematic. Either way, thanks for the suggestion.